# "Numeric value out of range" error when using SQLFetch() with SQL_C_FLOAT

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I have 2 computers.

The first one (A) with Windows Server 2003 and SQL Server 2000 installed. There is a database exist on this computer. This database added to ODBC data sources with SQLServer driver version - 2000.85.1022.

Second one (B) with Windows 7 64bit. Database from computer A also added to ODBC data sources via SQLServer Native Client. Driver version - 2007.100.1600.22.

I have the software which connects to the database using ODBC data source, retrives some data and perform calculations. The code looks like:

```
wsprintf ((LPSTR)m_stmt,"select field1 from MyTable Order by field1");  

float field1Val;
SQLExecDirectEx(m_hstmt,m_stmt,SQL_NTS);
SQLBindCol(m_hstmt, 1, SQL_C_FLOAT, &field1Val, 0, &cbCustID);
m_retcode = SQLFetch(m_hstmt);
```

When I invoke this software on the computer A everything works fine.
**When I invoke it on the computer B connection performs well but after using SQLFetch() I'm getting "Numeric value out of range" error (22003).**

field1 declared in database as decimal 9(18:2). The value stored is "0.50"

**So the question is how to make it work on computer B.**

The DB wasn't created by me and I'm not a database expert at all. So hope you can help me.

Thanks.

p.s. when I'm fetching the value using SQL_C_CHAR everything works fine.

Comment: Is 0.50 the only value present? Can you try other values(0.00, 1.00, say)?

Comment: No difference. Other values produce the same result

Comment: SQLExecDirectEx doesn't seem to exist, only SQLExecDirect. Do you have sample code that actually produces the problem?

Comment: Sorry for this, SQLExecDirectEx is just a wrapper on SQLExecDirect with added logging. The code I've pasted in the question is the one that produces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Windows 7 64 bit.
SQL Server 2008 64 bit.

Trying to do an SQLGetData with SQL_C_DOUBLE on a Decimal field in the Database.

I presume there is something wrong with the SQL Native Client Driver.

On 32 bit Windows 7 it works fine

On 64 bit Windows 7 with the MDAC driver it works fine

The solution in the end for me was to install the SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client driver.

Although as this requires an extra redistributable I will be testing and distributing SQL 2008 R2 instead

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem, but I would personally *never* use the float data type in my C code. It may be worth trying:

```
double field1Val;
SQLBindCol(m_hstmt, 1, SQL_C_DOUBLE, &field1Val, 0, &cbCustID);
```

Comment: That is not my code but I need to make some changes in it. I tried "double" but it doesn't solve the problem.